# How can i put a border bottom INSIDE my <li> menu?

Tags: html, css

Here is my menu :

[image: http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/11/1457970638-capture-d-ecran-2016-03-14-a-16-47-36.png]

Here is my li css :

```
li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 25px 20px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `box-sizing` property to `border-box`:

```
li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 25px 20px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li><a href="#">About</a></li><li><a href="#">Stuff</a></li>
</ul>
```